# Generating salts with a constant in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encryption, salt, bcrypt

So I'm relatively new to encryption, and stackoverflow, so please tell me if I'm going about this wrong.

Bcrypt by default uses randomly generated salts in the digest to stop rainbow table attacks. These salts are stored in the database in the password digest.
Wouldn't it be more secure to have a constant stored only in code that you would add to the randomly generated salts. This, in theory, would require attackers to have both your database and your code to test passwords. I'd assume it would be built into bcrypt if there wasn't some flaw in my thinking, so where's the error in my idea?

Comment: Just being pedantic, but what you are talking about is not encryption, it is hashing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so, ground rules: No encryption is unbreakable, it's only a matter of time. "secure" encryption just means it would take unfeasibly long to break it.

In comes rainbow tables with pre-broken passwords. Now it takes no time at all, and the encryption is useless.

Enter the salt.  With a salt, you can't do any work in advance, and with individual salts, you can't re-use work either.

http://throwingfire.com/storing-passwords-securely/ is a good read.

At this point, it's not impossible to read passwords from your database, but it's as hard as it is to guess them outright, and  improving your encryption from this point on does nothing for you unless you start making your users passwords harder to guess.

Plus, if they have direct access to your DB, which you only store credentials for on your deployment machine, they are very likely to have access to other things on that machine, and there is many much easier ways to get your users passwords than brute force tests against your db. (rewriting your code to just send them the passwords as they are entered for example)

Answer (score 0):

Salts are random and different for each password so storing one string in code is less secure because when you get both code and database it will be easier to crack passwords. When you get everything right so good salt and good one way function it should resist brute force attacks (provided passwords are "strong"). What you suggest it is [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) and it is discouraged and not recommended.